# python. написать регулярное выражение для строки "<div class="class_1 class-2 class3"></div>"

Tags: python

как писать регулярное выражение для строки `<div class="class_1 class-2 class3"></div>`, чтобы вывелись только наименования классов (`class_1` `class-2` и `class3`) и только в единственном случае: если классы написаны внутри атрибута, а не просто кавычек?

file text.txt:

```html
<div class="qwerty hel_lo tuy-iy">content</div>
<div class="qwerty hel_lo tuy-iy">content</div>
<div class="qwerty hel_lo tuy-iy">content</div>
```

Comment: Парсить html с помощью регулярных выражений - это мазохизм (имхо). Могу посоветовать глянуть в сторону готовых парсеров, например [BeautifulSoap](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Там уже есть решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: – Bogdan да, но мне нужно сделать именно так

Comment: тогда вам нужна функция, которая из указанной строки выделит `class="class_1 class-2 class3"`, а потом отрежет `class=` и кавычки. Подобная функция вам подойдет?

Comment: – Bogdan даа!! и вы можете сделать так, чтобы классы выводились по отдельности, а не как целая строка?

Comment: Попробуйте `re.findall(r'class+[_-]*\d', '<div class="class_1 class-2 class3"></div>')`

Comment: – S. Nick работает, но когда пишу `with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
  contents = f.read()
 x = re.findall(r'class+[_-]*\d', contents)
 print(x)` выводит просто пустые скобки:( что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f: 
    for line in f:
        if '<div class="' in line:
            x = line.split('"')[1].split()
            if x:
                print(x)
```

Comment: Извините, не было времени проверить работает ли. вот не знаю почему, но у меня ничего не выводит. у вас как?

Comment: Опубликуйту в вопросе ваш файл `text.txt`

Comment: – S. Nick сделала

Comment: – S. Nick update: я не заметила `\d`, извините. но все равно, выводит только: `['class']['class']['class']`

Comment: Попробуйте обновленный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение с помощью регулярки

```
import re
a = """
<div class="qwerty hel_lo tuy-iy">content</div>
<div class="qwerty hel_lo tuy-iy">content</div>
<div class="qwerty hel_lo tuy-iy">content</div>
"""
a = a.replace("\n", "")

b = re.findall(r"class\s*?=\s*?\"(.*?)\"", a)
print(b)
```